# Class wont work from CSS file but works in HTML file

Tags: html, css

So I am building a website for myself and I am having some trouble with a class. My Html file is linked to my css file no problem because other bits of css are working but my class tag will not work.
Here is the bit of relevant html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>ABCD Home</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet1.css" />
    <style></style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="task_handler.php"> Task Handler </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="grocery_list.php"> Grocery List </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="3d_printers.php"> 3D Printer HUB </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="store.php"> Store </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="about.php"> About </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <div class=".socials">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCbScAAcSVrM1JRjN3ougp8w">
            YouTube
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

And here is the bit of the css, the nav element works just fine so maybe I am using the class wrong but I thought the following css would work

```
nav {
  background-color: goldenrod;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 5px;
  height: 30px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px 0 black;
}
nav * {
  display: inline;
}
nav li {
  margin: 20px;
}
nav li a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}
:global {
  .socials {
    background-color: goldenrod;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 5px;
    height: 30px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px 0 black;
  }
  .socials * {
    display: inline;
  }
  .socials li {
    margin: 20px;
  }
  .socials li a {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
}
```

I had initially declared it not as a global and it was not working so I have been troubleshooting. It doesn't seem to work either way

If I put the class declarations exactly as they are in the head of my html and within style tags it works just fine. like so

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>ABCD Home</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet1.css" />
    <style>
      .socials {
        background-color: goldenrod;
        position: fixed;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 5px;
        height: 30px;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        box-shadow: 0 0 10px 0 black;
      }
      .socials * {
        display: inline;
      }
      .socials li {
        margin: 20px;
      }
      .socials li a {
        color: black;
        text-decoration: none;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="task_handler.php"> Task Handler </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="grocery_list.php"> Grocery List </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="3d_printers.php"> 3D Printer HUB </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="store.php"> Store </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="about.php"> About </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <div class=".socials">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCbScAAcSVrM1JRjN3ougp8w">
            YouTube
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I don't see what's going on here.

Sorry for any formatting issues this is my first question.

Comment: Have you made sure that you're linking your CSS file properly? Currently, in your HTML code, it says that your CSS file is in the same folder/directory as your HTML file, with the name of `stylesheet1.css`. Is that right?

Comment: It is linked properly as the <nav> element and its css works no problem. I host my own webserver so the files are all in the same directory aside from some images.

Comment: Ah, ok, I see. The issue is that you have `class='.socials'`. All you need is `class='socials'` and that should be enough. Keep the CSS the way it is `.socials {}` and try again. I also recommend removing the `:global` thing.

Comment: I had tried that already. The .social was also part of my troubleshooting. Ill give it another shot. I have already removed the global as I didn't think it was doing anyhting.

Comment: Well something either you suggested or I changed fixed it but now I've lost a background image. I will keep troubleshooting.

Comment: There is no such thing as `:global` in plain CSS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would appear that it was a formatting issue. I have changed the CSS to be outside of the global statement and I have made sure the  is calling the correct class as in `<div class="socials">`
After saving and uploading all the files it seems to work.